# Does this quadratic system admit an integral or a rational solution?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, quadratic-forms, rational-points, diophantine-geometry

Let $a,b$ be coprime and say $0<a<b<2a$.

Consider the quadratic system:

$$\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1$$
$$(\alpha^2-(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma))a^2b+\beta^2b^3+(2\alpha\beta-\beta\delta)ab^2-\alpha\gamma a^3=0$$
$$(-\alpha\gamma+2\gamma\delta)a^2b+(\delta^2-(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma))ab^2-\beta\delta b^3+\gamma^2a^3=0$$

1. Does it admit an integral solution in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$? Is so, then is there a polynomial time algorithm in $\log|ab|$?

I think there are no integral solutions. We get the criteria

$$\beta^2\equiv\beta\delta\equiv 0\bmod a$$
$$\gamma^2\equiv\alpha\gamma\equiv 0\bmod b$$

This constraint seems very restrictive with respect to $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1$.

2. If not, then does it admit a rational solution in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$? Is so, then is there a polynomial time algorithm in $\log|ab|$?

Comment: $A,B$ should be $a,b$?  Or vice-versa.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay yes corrected thank you.

Comment: A rational solution (maybe all of them???) is given by arbitrary $\beta,\delta$ and
$$\alpha = \frac{a^2+\beta^2b^2-\beta\delta ab}{a(\delta a-\beta b)}, \quad
   \gamma = \frac{b(a+\beta\delta b-\delta^2 a)}{a(\delta a-\beta b)}.$$

Comment: An integer solution (but probably not all of them) is given by $\alpha=-1-abk$, $\beta=ka^2$, $\gamma=-kb^2$, $\delta=abk-1$, where $k$ is an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Also change the two "$-1$"s into "$+1$" for another solution.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay could you please elaborate how you got them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comments I employed Maple, which uses tools like Grobner bases to solve polynomial equations. But now I'll try to do it by hand. Let $E_1,E_2,E_3$ be the three equations. A rational solution of $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ can be turned into an integer solution of $\{E_2,E_3\}$ by multiplying by a common denominator, so I'll first look for integer solutions of $\{E_2,E_3\}$.  Coprimality of $a,b$ is silently assumed throughout and variables are integer unless specified otherwise.

From $E_2$, $\beta$ is a multiple of $a$, while from $E_3$, $\gamma$ is a multiple of $b$. Put $\beta=ax, \gamma=by$. Now (using $a,b\ne 0$), the equations factor:
\begin{align}
  (bx+\alpha)(ay-bx-\alpha+\delta)&=0.\tag{$E_{2a}$} \\
  (ay+\delta)(ay-bx-\alpha+\delta)&=0.\tag{$E_{3a}$}
\end{align}
The first case is $\alpha=-bx$, which turns $E_{3a}$ into $(ay+\delta)^2=0$ so $\delta=-ay$. So this integer
solution of $\{E_2,E_3\}$ is
$$ \alpha=-bx, \beta=ax, \gamma=by, \delta=-ay.$$
However, this gives $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=0$ so we can't
satisfy $E_1$ even by scaling. So this solution is discarded.

The second case is $ay-bx-\alpha+\delta=0$, which is a factor
of both $E_{2a}$ and $E_{3a}$. So we can choose $\delta$ arbitrarily and set $\alpha=ay-bx+\delta$. So this integer solution of $\{E_2,E_3\}$ is
$$ \alpha = ay-bx+\delta, \beta=ax, \gamma=by. \tag{S} $$
We can locate all **rational solutions of $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$**
by uniformly scaling $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ to satisfy $E_1$. However, the scale factor might be irrational so we must be careful. What we need is that $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=\rho^2$ where $\rho$ is some rational number. Solving that for $x$, substituting and scaling down by $\rho$,
we find that all rational solutions of $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ have the form
$$ \alpha=\frac{a^2y^2+awy+\rho^2}{(ay+w)\rho},
  \beta=\frac{(w^2+awy-\rho^2)a}{b(ay+w)\rho},
  \gamma=\frac{by}{\rho}, \delta=\frac{w}{\rho} $$
for arbitrary integer $y,w$ and rational $\rho$.
If we allow $y,w$ to be rational, we can dispense with $\rho$:
$$ \alpha=\frac{a^2y^2+awy+1}{ay+w},
  \beta=\frac{(w^2+awy-1)a}{b(ay+w)},
  \gamma=by, \delta=w. $$

Now looking for **integer solutions of $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$** we must satisfy $E_1$.
Substituting (S) into $E_1$ we get
$$ (bx-\delta)(ay+\delta)=-1. \tag{$E_1b$} $$
So we have $bx-\delta=1,ay+\delta=-1$ or vice-versa.
Both options give $(bx-\delta)^2=1$, so $\delta=bx\pm 1$,
and also $ay+bx=0$.
Since $a,b$ are coprime, we can satisfy $ay+bx=0$ only with $x=az, y=-bz$.

In summary, the integer solutions of $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ are
\begin{align*}
\alpha&=1-abz,\beta=a^2z,\gamma=-b^2z,\delta=1+abz \\
\alpha&=-1-abz,\beta=a^2z,\gamma=-b^2z,\delta=-1+abz.
\end{align*}
for arbitrary integer $z$.